# How to restore a differential backup without the full backup?

Tags: sql-server

I am a new to SQL server and I need to restore a differential backup for every 4 hrs and a full backup once in a day.

The problem is, that each time I try to restore a differential backup it is asking me to restore the full backup, although I have already restored it (the full backup).

Is there any way to skip the full backup and restore the differential backup?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be on the database admin SE site